# Django-behave - no behave tests

Tags: django-tests, python-behave

Does someone has expiriences with django-behave? I can not run behave tests.
I have newests versions of '`behave'` and `'django-behave'` installed. `'django_behave'` is in my `INSTALLED_APPS` and in my settings.py i also added `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_behave.runner.DjangoBehaveTestSuiteRunner'`.
I have working django project. Some files and directories of it goes like so:

```
mysite/
      mysite/
             settings.py
             ...(other)
      example_app/
                  features/
                          example.feature
                          steps/
                               example.py
```

When I prompt 'python manage.py test' in a command line I can see that test are performed normally, without behave things.
   What I am missing?

Comment: Is this still an issue? - What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
python manage.py test example_app
```